# How to save localStorage setted dynamically from onclick this.nameClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

So, i have this javascript code:

```
function check(x) {
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName(x);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
}
```

With this code, i can change the backgroundColor of anything with any class in my html page.

I have many "a" tags with differents class, for example:

```
<a class="1" onclick="check(this.className)">text 1</a>
<a class="2" onclick="check(this.className)">text 2</a>
<a class="3" onclick="check(this.className)">text 3</a>
<a class="4" onclick="check(this.className)">text 4</a>
```

And when I click on then I can change background color.

My problem is when I try to save this change in localStorage. I´m wanting to save the background color change to, on load page, check if users have clicked to change background color or not, for example:

```
function check(x) {
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName(x);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
    if (localStorage[x] != "yellow") {
        elements[i].style.color = "yellow";
        localStorage[x] = "yellow";
    } else {
        elements[i].style.color = "";
        localStorage[x] = "";
    }

}
window.onload = function() {
    if (localStorage[x]) {
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor = localStorage[x];
    }

}
```

This is the way i found to highlight text user think is interting and he wants to mark, but this is not working.
Can someone helps me with this?

Comment: can you tell me where it breaks

Comment: when debug, right click on Inspect Elemnt in chrome, then go to console, see what errors

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
function check(x) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(x);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }

    var colors = localStorage.getItem('colors');
    colors = colors ? colors.split(',') : [];

    if (colors.indexOf(x) == -1) {
        colors.push(x);
        localStorage.setItem('colors', colors.join(','));
    }
    console.log(colors, localStorage.getItem('colors'))

}
window.onload = function () {
    var colors = localStorage.getItem('colors');
    if (colors) {
        colors = colors.split(',');
        for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            check(colors[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/201mL4nr/)

Comment: this works great for me... Thanks. But i have i question yet, then if, after click and localStorage backgroundColor, i want to change and save backgroundColor=null to come back to original form, how can i do that?

Comment: few years later but you should mark the solution given by "Arun P Johny" as "answered" as it looks like that's what you decided to use. "Thanks", "+1", or other useless comments are not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in a for loop:

```
function check(x) {
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName(x);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        if (localStorage[x] != "yellow") {
            elements[i].style.color = "yellow";
            localStorage[x] = "yellow";
        } else {
            elements[i].style.color = "";
            localStorage[x] = "";
        }

    }
}
window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (localStorage[x]) {
            elements[i].style.backgroundColor = localStorage[x];
        }
    }
}
```

Note that i have `document.getElementsByClassName("a")` in the second loop, replace "a" with whatever class that all your  tags share.

Comment: i did this, but i have many "a" tags, maybe 100 or more, if i need to set 1 by 1 i will lose much time.